# Datagrid bound to Dataset not updating

Tags: wpf, datagrid, notifydatasetchanged

I've a DataGrid which is bound to a BindingListCollectionView ("MyView") which refers to a Dataset.table.defaultview.
When I refresh the Data inside the MicrosoftSQL Table the DataTable in a Timer gets updated, but not the datagrid in my view.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyView, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyDown="dataGrid1_KeyDown" />
```

code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataSet _exhibitionTeam;
    private static string CONN_STRING = @"Server=testServer;Database=TestDB;Uid=TestUser;Pwd=TestPwd;";
    string SELECT_SQL = "SELECT kurzzeichen,name,mail,telefon from pers_didacta";
    BackgroundWorker worker;

    private BindingListCollectionView _view;

    public BindingListCollectionView MyView
    {
        get { return this._view; }
        protected set
        {
            this._view = value;
            //this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.MyView);
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyView");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _exhibitionTeam = new DataSet("dsExhibitionTeam");
        ReadDataIntoDataSet();

        this.MyView = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_exhibitionTeam.Tables["Team"].DefaultView);

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RefreshDataIntoDataSet();
            this.MyView.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }


    public DataSet ExhibitionTeam
    {
        get
        {
            return _exhibitionTeam;
        }
        set
        {
            _exhibitionTeam = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ExhibitionTeam");
        }
    }

    private void ReadDataIntoDataSet()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN_STRING))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT_SQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter myMySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            myMySqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            myMySqlDataAdapter.Fill(_exhibitionTeam, "Team");
            myMySqlDataAdapter.Dispose(); //not needed any longer!
        }
    }

    private void RefreshDataIntoDataSet()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN_STRING))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataSet myDataSet;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT_SQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter myMySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            myMySqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            myDataSet = new DataSet("dsExhibitions");
            myMySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Team");
            ExhibitionTeam.Merge(myDataSet, false);
            myMySqlDataAdapter.Dispose(); //not needed any longer!
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void dataGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshDataIntoDataSet();
    }
}
```

When i press any key on my datagrid the data gets updated. But the same method from my background worker will not work.

I also tried to bind against ExhibitionTeam.Tables[Team] but this is the same result.

What is wrong in my solution? Why is my datagrid not updating?
The Dataset updates during the merge (seen in debugger).

Later I want to update the Dataset via Detecting Changes with SqlDependency.

Answer (score 0):

if you debug your code and the value in your datatable are ok after

```
ExhibitionTeam.Merge(myDataSet, false);
```

then you can simply call

```
this.MyView.Refresh();
```

i dont know if the merge raise notifypropertychanged